# How to save void * data into a header file?

Tags: c, image, export, header-files

I am currently working on images and procedurally generate images then convert them into dds or rtc1. Due to constrains of my program, I cannot open external files so I want them embedded with the code.

I found out GIMP has a "c header" exporter but i'd like to do that myself for my generated
textures.

Using void* would allow this to be used for any types of data.

UPDATE: To clarify things, I was thinking about outputting as unsigned int like this:

```
void exportToHeader(const void* data, const uin32_t size, const char* name)
{
    uint32_t* pData = (uint32_t*)data;

    printf("void* %s = {\n");

    // TODO: handle last case
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        printf("%s, ", pData[i]);
    }

    printf("};\n");            
}
```

Will the compiler be able to understand this ?

Comment: Can you give more details about what you want to do ?

Comment: If you know the data, why not use the correct data type? For example, if you want to output RGBA data, why not an array of arrays of four `unsigned char` (i.e. `unsigned char image[][4] = { { R1, G1, B1, A1 }, ... };`)

Comment: Using int allows me to work on 4 char at the time so less iterations, speeding things up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correct what you want to do is to import a binary image into your C code.

So what I would do in this case is, to write a simple program which dumps a file as a list of bytes and write an output like this:

```
char mydata[] = { 122, 334, 45, ... };
```

Then you can simply include this file and reference your texture like any other C array.

To dump the file is rather simple (in pseudocode).

```
file = open(file);
printf("char mydata[] = {\n");
while(file != eof)
{
    c = getc(file);
    printf("%d, ", c);
}
close(file);
printf("\n\;\n");
```

Whith this you can include any binary file in your C code.

Comment: I think your last `printf` is missing a `}`. Also it is probably better to use `unsigned char` for binary data, so you'd be sure that you don't run into problems with signed or unsigned implementations of `char`.

Comment: It's just pseudocode to given an idea, so it doesn't have to compile, but you are right. Escpecially the unsigned char might be a good idea. On the other hand, if the strcuture of the data is well known, I wouldn't use it like this anyway, and rather create a struct pointing to the data when coding the access to the data. After all, this would be just the binary data as you would have read it from the file.

Comment: Interesting how you try to use '334' as an initializer for an element of an array of type `char`...

Comment: @ElchononEdelson, I guess the poster got the idea nevertheless. ;)

Answer (score 1):

I ended up doing this:

```
        uint32_t* intData = (uint32_t*)data; 
        for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
            if (i == size -1) {
                fprintf(fp, "%uu };", intData[i]);
            } else {
                fprintf(fp, "%uu, ", intData[i]);
            }
        }
```

Of course you must make sure that you are aligned on 4 bytes to be able to convert to uint32_t*